# Applying for a US job as a fresh graduate in the US, ineligible for OPT

Tags: working-visas, students, h1-visa

I had to take a break from my US studies (B.S. in Computer Science) for health reasons and got back during my last semester, Spring 2015. Unfortunately since I had to restart my status as a International Student, I am not eligible for OPT work authorization unless I stay a student for at least two consecutive terms, meaning I would have to enroll in a Master's (for which I have neither the funds nor the passion).

I know that the work-visa cut-off for employers is April 1st.

Am I screwed?

Comment: So it wasn't a sanctioned medical leave of absence?

Comment: No, I do not think so. I was not aware that it had to be treated as such, since I ended up missing the next two (Summer and Fall) terms due to surgery (which ended up having long-lasting aftereffects). During my visa restart process I supplied documentation from the surgery, however.

Comment: Probably want to be clearer n what you're asking. If it's merely "Am I screwed" it comes down to opinion based. I'd edit it based on the [help] and flag to reopen.